# How can I create a volcano plot in r using muma package

Tags: r

I've been trying to create a volcano plot using the muma package in r but I've had some difficulties in importing my data in CSV format, every time I try to run the code (below) I get this error message.

If you know an easier way to create a volcano plot, using a different package,  it would really help me.

thanks

```
explore.data(file="datosFin_A1AT.csv",scaling="Auto", scal = TRUE, normalize = TRUE,
             imputation = TRUE, imput="mean")
```

Error in `[.data.frame`(comp, , 3:ncol(comp)) :
undefined columns selected

```
structure(list(Muestra = c("MI-001", "MI-003", "MI-009", "MI-012"), Class = c("Presencia", 
"Ausencia", "Presencia", "Ausencia"), Per_Cintura = c(97.6, 92.8, 98.8, 113.4), HDL = c(38, 51, 51, 44), TG = c("195", "76", "160", "128"), ApoB = c(145, 161, 173, 50.9), Glucosa_mg=c(86, 85, 96, 79, 7), LBP = c(443.187, 438.925, 703.752, 
540.541), IFABP = c(0.705485, 0.906843, 144.873, 145.884), CLD3 = c(0.2, 501.596, 315.582, 446.307), Acetico = c(NA, 745.654, NA, 105.378), Propionico = c(NA, 682.719, 86.628, 303.139), Butirico = c(NA, 571.421, 265.559, 135.674), Isobutirico = c(286.085, 0.0381631, 0.276992, 0.0467809), prevotella = c(0.12843, 0.07927, 0.22459, 0.01726), Pathogen=c(0.05639, 0.16051, 0.01617, 0.04398), Lachnospiraceae = c(0.24202, 0.73606, 0.67789, 0.62656), Aker_Bacter = c(0.06167, 0.00999, 0.03426, 0.0211), Ruminoco = c(0.33593, 3e-05, 0.01538, 0.01298), TNFa = c(14.16, 35.35, 43.71, 42.99), PCR = c(1.71, 1.84, 3.52, 2.32), IL33 = c(148.7, 207.6, 146.2, 162.6), IL8 = c(157.9, 115.3, NA, NA), IL1b = c(13.68, 12.36, 13.69, 19.06), IL18 = c(231.6, 293.5, 366.2, 298.5)))
```

Comment: In explore. data , 'file'  has to be a matrix in .csv form, I did not upload the csv file but the structure of the data in that document

Comment: i'm guessing `read.csv` is not separating your columns correctly, it could be you have a file with a csv extension but is separated by whitespace. you can go through the lines of code in [this function](https://github.com/cran/muma/blob/master/R/explore.data.R#L6) to see how your data look at each step. you are getting an error at the second line so it shouldn't take very long